# Is there a way to remove the lagg?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I get lagg in my XNA game. It is because I put in too many enemies. If I remove a part of them there isnt lagg anymore. Is ther a way to remove the lagg?  to do that I think I could update them part by part. It doesn't function with a normal if(). All my enemies are put in like this:

```
List<enemy1> enemies1= new List<enemy1>();

LoadContent()
{
    foreach(enemy1 enemy in enemies1)
        enemy.Load(Content);

    enemies1.Add(new enemy1(new Vector2(500,500)));
}

Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach(enemy1 enemy in enemies1)
        enemy.Update(gameTime);
}

Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    foreach(enemy1 enemy in enemies1)
        enemy.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

I also remove them after killing. The map is kinda big (12700x12700)

Comment: Only draw enemies that are visible within the viewport, no point rendering those which you can't see

Comment: What causes the lag, the update or the draw ?

Comment: @OopsUser the proper render.

Comment: the update causes the lagg (and the loadContent if i put in too many)

Comment: Don't load content for EVERY enemy, if they all look the same, make a statc `LoadContent` method with a static texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Draw function to this

```
Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GraphicsDevice device)
{
    Point tempPoint;
    foreach (enemy1 enemy in enemies1)
    {
        tempPoint = new Point((int)enemy.Position.X, (int)enemy.Position.Y)
        if (device.Viewport.Bounds.Contains(tempPoint))
            enemy.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will cause problems when objects are at the edge of the screen. But it is a step in the right direction. If it does cause problems you will need to test the sides of your sprites rather than the position.

Comment: Or just copy the rectangle to a separate object and 'inflate' it by a bunch of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

where are you calling spritebatch.begin()?

I have a feeling that you are calling it in enemy.draw(). You should only call it once, like this:

```
Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
{
    spriteBatch.begin();
    foreach(enemy1 enemy in enemies1)
        enemy.Draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```